# TemplateDoesNotExist Django Error only on VPS - works fine locally

Tags: python, django

I know that there are many other questions like this one, but I believe my case is unique - I have spent hours, applying fixes from literally every website and youtube tutorial I have come across, and I still get this error. I am wondering why:

Here is the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /skills/
skills\skills.html
```

Here is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for pranavblog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['host1',host2','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'posts',
    'sitepages',
    'hackathons',
    'projects',
    'pagedown',
    'skills.apps.SkillsConfig',
    'django.forms'
]
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pranavblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pranavblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
SITE_ID = 1

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/pics/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Skill
# Create your views here.

def skills(request):
    Skills = Skill.objects.all()
    return render(request,'skills\skills.html', {"Skills":Skills})

def skill_details(request, skill_id):
    skills = get_object_or_404(Skill, pk=skill_id)
    return render(request,'skills/skill_details.html', {'skill':skills})
```

And finally, here is my URL for the skills pages

```
path('skills/',skills.views.skills,name="skills"),
path('skills/<int:skill_id>/', skills.views.skill_details,name="skill_details")
```

Oddly, this error occurs solely during the deployment to an external VPS. When I run the code locally and navigate to the localhost, everything works fine. When I deploy the code to the website and navigate to the website's URL for the skills tab, it throws the TemplateDoesNotExist error.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I use FileZilla for file transfer and gunicorn and nginx for the website. Every time I make a change, I restart ngninx and gunicorn - it is not because of that.

Comment: It can be related to read permissions on templates. Also, I can see a mix of forward and backward slashes in your template paths in views.

Comment: Should I use forward or back slashes?

Comment: Oh my god - it really was because of the different slashes. I just fixed that small slash and the problem is gone now.

Comment: @PranavE you must be working on Windows ? Windows's filesystem now accepts both forward and backward slashes as separators (it used to accept only backward slashes), but unix-like OSs only use forward slashes.

Comment: My own computer is on windows, but my VPS is not. It is ubuntu - hence the errors.

Answer (score 1):

## The Answer:

I accidentally used a couple backslashes '\' where I should be only using forward slashes '/'. Gotta be careful to fix that next time.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

You should define directory of template like following, in your settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I have tried this, it has not fixed the problem. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can I see your nginx config?

Comment: Could you direct me as to where I can find this?

Comment: How you config your web server?

Comment: It's usually in /etc/nginx/sites-availabel/ directory

Comment: or maybe you have permission problem

Comment: Here is the dropbox link for the screenshot of my ngninx config https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qbgj4gwb6jfrch/nginx_config.PNG?dl=0. Thanks for helping me find it. I will not be on until tomorrow, around 8 PST, so I might not respond to your questions. Just informing you. Thanks.